# Android Studio says Flutter and Dart plugins are installed, but Flutter Doctor says they are not

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Android Studio 2020.3.1 says that both Flutter and Dart plugins are installed, but when I run "flutter doctor", it says these plugins are not installed.

I am at my wits end.

SDK Platforms: Android 10.0(Q), Android 9.0(Pie)
SDK Tools: Android SDK Build-Tools 32, Android SDK Command-line tools (latest), Android SDK Emulator, and Android SDK Platform-Tools.
OS: Windows 10

Flutter:

`C:\Users\Owner>flutter doctor
[v] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1415], locale en-US)`

[v] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[v] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[!] Connected device
! No devices available

Comment: Please attach the code from Flutter Doctor.

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: Operating system is Windows 10

Comment: I added the flutter output in the original post (could get it to format as code in the comment section using backticks, spacing, <code> tags, anything).

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to set your android sdk location and flutter sdk location in environment variables if you are using windows.